# Not able to access 2nd db created in 12c

Tags: oracle, oracle12c

I have installed Oracle 12c db in my system and a db with name *xyz* is created during installation. I have created another DB say *zzz* through Database and Configuration Assistant but 2nd DB is not accessible through SQL Developer whereas 1st db is accessible through SQL developer. Credentials are set for both of them and same. Error I am getting is

> ORA-12505, TNS:listener does not currently know of SID/service

I have selected all default settings. No changes were made in selections while creating both databases

Answer (score 0):

You can check if the database service is registered in the listener, and if so, under what service name (maybe it uses full name, or have a domain name as well):

```
lsnrctl status
lsntctl service
```

If the database is not registered, connect locally and check what is the value for the parameters `local_listener` and `remote_listener`.

Another thing you can try is to manually register the database to the listener using `alter system register;` command

Answer (score 0):

Use 'tnsping zzz'.

if it is failed, then the second Db is not registered with listener. Register the 2nd DB with listener and try to connect.